# WorkManager retry not working

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I have a WorkManager with custom [backoff policy](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkRequest.Builder#setBackoffCriteria(androidx.work.BackoffPolicy,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)). But this does not work.

- I would like to trigger a retry after the min backoff time which is 10 seconds.
- If the Worker jobs are kept in the WorkManager they get executed at random times / after restarting the application (I did not figure out when they are triggered, even if stated default is 30 seconds).

**Enque the Worker**

```
public void startWorker() {
    Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
        .build();
         Log.i("WorkManager", "starting workmanager");

        OneTimeWorkRequest work = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(UploadWorker.class)
                .setInitialDelay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .setBackoffCriteria(BackoffPolicy.LINEAR, WorkRequest.MIN_BACKOFF_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) // Custom retry not working
            .build();

    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(work);
}
```

**Worker**

```
public class UploadWorker extends Worker {

    @Override
    public Worker.Result doWork() {

        // Do the work here--in this case, compress the stored images.
        // In this example no parameters are passed; the task is
        // assumed to be "compress the whole library."
        Log.i("WorkManager", "do some stuff " + getId());

        // Indicate success or failure with your return value:
        return Result.RETRY;

        // (Returning RETRY tells WorkManager to try this task again
        // later; FAILURE says not to try again.)
    }
}
```

**Some logs of the tests**

```
08-21 18:16:05.064 8994-8994/com.worker.test I/WorkManager: starting workmanager
08-21 18:16:05.134 8994-9037/com.worker.test I/WorkManager: do some stuff a3f6ca8f-3b05-4691-bd29-dfec720045e9
08-21 18:16:05.136 8994-9037/com.worker.test I/WorkerWrapper: Worker result RETRY for Work [ id=a3f6ca8f-3b05-4691-bd29-dfec720045e9, tags={ com.worker.test.UploadWorker } ]
08-21 18:16:28.770 8994-8994/com.worker.test I/WorkManager: starting workmanager
08-21 18:16:28.807 8994-9039/com.worker.test I/WorkManager: do some stuff 396e6018-4b6c-478d-aaf4-a69ab5f555dd
08-21 18:16:28.808 8994-9039/com.worker.test I/WorkerWrapper: Worker result RETRY for Work [ id=396e6018-4b6c-478d-aaf4-a69ab5f555dd, tags={ com.worker.test.UploadWorker } ]
08-21 18:17:11.600 8994-8994/com.worker.test I/WorkManager: starting workmanager
08-21 18:17:11.659 8994-9076/com.worker.test I/WorkManager: do some stuff c4edd69c-e465-435f-8252-3e4973a320c7
08-21 18:17:11.661 8994-9076/com.worker.test I/WorkerWrapper: Worker result RETRY for Work [ id=c4edd69c-e465-435f-8252-3e4973a320c7, tags={ com.worker.test.UploadWorker } ]
```

I'm using the verion `1.0.0-alpha07` of `work-runtime`.

**Is this a Bug or am I missing something?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue just got fixed and will be available in alpha08.

https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/735900

Comment: I'm using `work-runtime:1.0.0-beta02` and it is still not working. `Result.retry()` never reties my worker while constraints are met.. very frustrating